# Handling the OAuth2 Client Credentials flow

Tags: oauth-2.0

I'm having trouble wrapping my head around implementing the client-credentials flow on the client side. Say the client requests a secure endpoint in an API without being authorized. The API will respond with 401 and that's that? As i understand it the client-credential flow should not require any user interaction, am i correct? Specifically, the client should not need to click, say, a button "Authorize client" before visiting any page that accesses protected resources?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right that there is no user interaction necessary. However, you must call the /token endpoint (with your credentials) to get back a token that you will later use in your API request's Authorization header.

Comment: The things that bugs me are
1) What initiates the call to the /token endpoint?
2) When returning from the token endpoint the user must navigate to the requested page again

Or am i just not thinking about this correctly?

Comment: 1) the client application makes the http request to the token endpoint. The response will contain the token. 2) the user doesn't need to navigate anywhere. The client credentials flow is for the "client" (i.e. the application...not the user). With the client credentials flow, the token is indistinguishable between users of the system. The same token would be used for any number of users on the system since it's the "client" that is authorized...not the user.

Comment: I get that, let me try to explain it better.

My client is a webpage. The homepage ("/") doesn't interact with the API at all. So no requests that need a token are used. So no token is fetched yet.
User then navigates to a different page ("/products") that uses the API to fetch all products. The request to the API will fail as i don't have a token yet and just return a JSON response with an error (401). This needs to be handled somehow, but i'm at a loss here

Comment: you need to get a token. a strategy could be that if you get a 401, call the token endpoint to get a token and then call the API endpoint again with the token you got back